# How to see scala compilation error on the project tree?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

[image]I can see java compilation error immediately on the project tree, but for scala code, I could not see that. Anyone know how to achieve that ?

Comment: Doesn't it highlight lines with red? What IDE are you using?

Comment: I use intellij and  upload the screenshot. I can see the redline on the editor, but could not see that on the project tree.